# Refactoring a for loop

Tags: python, loops, parallel-processing, cython, swig

as a result of a profiling study, I have found that this function is creating a bottleneck for my code to run faster.

```py
TM1 = TermMap(self.sums, self.tensors)
for xs in product(*tlists):
    sign = math.prod([x[1] for x in xs])
    newtensors = [permute(t, x[0]) for t, x in zip(other.tensors, xs)]
    TM2 = TermMap(other.sums, newtensors)
    if TM1 == TM2:
        return sign
return None
```

I would like to refactor in a way that I can either parallelize it, or at least compile it using SWIG or similar.

I tried `numba` but the `jit` class is not really working since the code handles many string and symbolic lists which produces a lot of errors in `numba`.

I have been facing the problem that parallelization using `mp` processes is complicated since the function is returning a `None`
and the condition `TM1 == TM2` is returning sign within the loop. I don't really know how to handle this, the re write the function that the mp.(i)map approach can be used.

The function `TermMap` and `permute` are part of other classes and therefore I don't really see how I can compile the `for` loop with these functions inside. Any ideas of suggestions to make this part of the code more efficient are welcome.

`tlists` is a list in this form:

```
[[((0, 1, 2, 3), 1), ((1, 0, 2, 3), -1), ((0, 1, 3, 2), -1), ((1, 0, 3, 2), 1)], [((0,), 1)], [((0, 1, 2, 3), 1), ((1, 0, 2, 3), -1), ((0, 1, 3, 2), -1), ((1, 0, 3, 2), 1)], [((0,), 1)], [((0, 1), 1)], [((0, 1), 1)], [((0, 1), 1)]]
```

However, it changes the size since this function is called many times inside another `for` loop.

Comment: Your code is not reproducible: what are product, permute, other, self, etc.

Comment: look into numpy or pandas.  if you can turn some python objects into buffers with numpy dtypes on them, and ditch a bunch of `for` then it should speed up.  reason for this is that python does a lot of extra checks for exceptions and the like on each iteration.  parallel processing- look at what the python gil is and you'll better understand the limitations.

Comment: What makes your code expensive? Complexity? memory access? Is it embarassiblgy parallel?

Comment: Hi there, thanks to Demi-Lune answer. Product is the function provided by itertools. 
I have a list of objects like: [[((0, 1, 2, 3), 1), ((1, 0, 2, 3), -1), ((0, 1, 3, 2), -1), ((1, 0, 3, 2), 1)], [((0,), 1)], [((0, 1, 2, 3), 1), ((1, 0, 2, 3), -1), ((0, 1, 3, 2), -1), ((1, 0, 3, 2), 1)], [((0,), 1)], [((0, 1), 1)], [((0, 1), 1)], [((0, 1), 1)]]

Comment: self.sums and aelf.tensors are objects provided by other two classes. The result provided by the function TermMap is a set with the following structure: 
{('!', (('occ', frozenset({'0I0', '0!0'})),)), ('T1', (('occ', frozenset({'1L20', '1T11'})), ('vir', frozenset({'0I3', '0T10'})))), ('T1', (('occ', frozenset({'1L21', '1T11'})), ('vir', frozenset({'0I2', '0T10'})))), ('L2', (('occ', frozenset({'0T11x', '1T11', '1L21', '0L20x'})), ('vir', frozenset({'2T10', '3L23', '3!0', '2L22'})))}. These are functions declare by other classes inside the code.

Comment: Based on an analysis of cProfile, the most expensive part of the code is the creation of TM2, then the comparisong to TM1. The for loop is iterating over a bunch of small mini lists like the ones I posted in my original question. I can send you the GitHub repository where the full code is hosted.

Comment: Abel, thank you very much. I tried also in the part of math.prod to use numpy prod, trying to get advantage of the parallelisation provided there. However, there was no speed up, even though I saw in my htop the use of multiprocesses from time to time.

Comment: The GIL will prevent any speed up using multiple threads since you are working with pure-Python objects. Using multiple process could be slow because of the time to create processes and send them the input data (hard to tell without a reproducible example). Without knowing more about the hidden function `TermMap` we cannot help you further. Keep in mind that working with pure-Python object is slow even with Cython or Numba.

Comment: Thanks @Jerome, the termmap function is hosted here in this github: https://github.com/awhite862/wick/blob/master/wick/expression.py and the function that I am trying to refactor is called pmatch, that is in line 520 in the same file. Thanks!